# Codeigniter - Issue while trying to use postgresql

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter

I'm working on a ticket system on codeigniter that is supposed to handle postgresql, when i switch the driver to pgsql a lots of error shows up, it works fine if I switch back to mysql.

This is the errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$settings

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 21

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 21
```

this is the line 21 in Template php

```
public function loadContent($view,$data=array(),$die=0)

{
    $CI =& get_instance();

if(empty($this->layout)) {
    $this->set_layout($CI->settings->info->layout);
}
$site = array();
$site['cssincludes'] = $this->cssincludes;
foreach($this->data as $k=>$v) {
    $site[$k] = $v;
}
foreach($this->data as $k=>$v) {
    $data[$k] = $v;
}
$site['content'] = $CI->load->view($view,$data,true);
if($this->sidebar) {
    $site['sidebar'] = $CI->load->view($this->sidebar,$data,true);
}

if($this->page_title) {
    $site['page_title'] = $this->page_title;
}

if($this->responsive_sidebar) {
    $site['responsive_sidebar'] = $CI->load
        ->view($this->responsive_sidebar,$data,true);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it was a query error

Regards